# 3 white wires and 3 black wires. Only need 2 of each

Tags: light-fixture

What should I do with the extra black and white wire? The new light fixture has two lights, a black wire and a white wire for each. Should I assume just to pick any two and cover the extras with wire nuts?

Comment: Is there a switch involved?

Comment: Agree, duplicate. Other question is better because it includes a picture of such a fixture.

Answer (score 3):

Connect all the whites together and connect all the blacks together. This is known as wiring the two lights in the fixture in parallel.

Comment: If you wire only two, at best (if you pick the cable from the same bulb-socket) only a lamp will lit at worst none (if you pick a black from one lamp and with from the other)